# Is apple pay free to use when using a credit card at a shop?

Tags: apple-pay

I've added a credit card to my wallet/apple pay. According to my bank the service is free. But is it also free from the perspective of Apple? I've read that Apple gets 0,15% of each purchase but they get that from banks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won’t pay any extra to use Apple Pay (unless the retailer makes a surcharge for all card payments, in which case you’ll pay that surcharge) — Apple’s cut comes from the processing fee that the retailer pays.